# Difficulties with WHERE .. IN query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm currently developing an auction website for an online game. However, when creating the statistics I ran into a problem with the queries.

The problem is that I need to have all auction which I participated in and which I've lost. But so far Ive only seen to be able to get all lost auctions (not just the ones I participated in).

Assume I have the following tables:

**Table structure for table Auction**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Auction` (
  `id` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `preferedAuctionId` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `winningTicketId` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '-1',
  `createdOn` datetime NOT NULL,
  `startedOn` datetime NOT NULL,
  `finishedOn` datetime NOT NULL,
  `active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

---

--

### -- Table structure for table `AuctionBids`

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `AuctionBids` (
  `bidId` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `accountId` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `auctionId` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `ticketId` int(50) NOT NULL,
  `datetime` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`bidId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

**Below are some of the queries I have tried.**

```
SELECT * 
FROM Auction au, AuctionBids ab 
WHERE au.id = ab.auctionId AND au.winningTicketId = ab.ticketId AND 
      ab.accountId NOT LIKE '". $_accountId ."' AND 
      au.finishedOn NOT LIKE '0000-00-00 00:00:00' AND au.active = '0'
```

and

```
SELECT * 
FROM Auction 
WHERE winningTicketId NOT IN 
(    SELECT ticketId 
     FROM AuctionBids 
     WHERE accountId = '". $_accountId ."') 
   AND finishedOn NOT LIKE '0000-00-00 00:00:00' AND active = '0'
```

If you are missing any critical information, please ask me and I'll provide you.

Yours Sincerly,
Larssy1

---

Test on your localhost I have made a test dump:

http://pastebin.com/d412ESVa

Expected Results:

The person with accountId '{0D3FB1B2-1C0C-06EA-979A-15F5B5231E7C}' won all auctions he participated in, which means the rows returned by him should be 0.

The person with accountId '{65CC1576-C3C3-5AC1-8098-B8CF1347F481}' lost all auctions he participated in, which means the rows returned by him should be 1.

Comment: Show create table instead of your own notation.

Comment: It is the export format OpenDocument Text provided by PHPMyAdmin. I did change it into SQL now though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps so?

```
SELECT distinct a.* FROM Auction a JOIN AuctionBids ab ON a.id = ab.auctionId 
WHERE a.winningTicketId not in 
(select ticketId from AuctionBids WHERE accountId = '". $_accountId ."'
and a.id = auctionId) 
AND a.id in
(select auctionId from AuctionBids WHERE accountId = '". $_accountId ."')
AND a.active = '0'
AND finishedOn NOT LIKE '0000-00-00 00:00:00';
```

Edited. Try it in [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6e83e/28)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for a joined table. I assume the winningTicket field holds the winning ticket id.

```
SELECT * 
FROM Auction JOIN AuctionBids ON Auction.id=AuctionBids.auctionId
WHERE Auction.active=0 AND 
      AuctionBids.accountId=yourAccountID AND 
      Auction.winningTicket<>AuctionBids.ticketId
```

Maybe this will help or get you on the right way?

=== Update ===

What if you do this:

```
SELECT 
    Auction.id AS auctionID,
    Auction.winningTicketId,
    SUM( IF(Auction.winningTicketId=AuctionBids.ticketId, IF(AuctionBids.accountId=yourID,1,0 ),0) ) AS youWON,
    SUM( IF(AuctionBids.accountId=yourID,1,0) ) AS nYouBID
FROM Auction JOIN AuctionBids ON Auction.id=AuctionBids.auctionId
WHERE
    Auction.active=0
GROUP BY Auction.id
ORDER BY youWON ASC, nYouBID DESC, auctionID ASC
```

- Replace yourID with "{0D3FB1B2-1C0C-06EA-979A-15F5B5231E7C}"
  SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dd8a9/15

This will provide a row per non-active auction with two bools if you are the winner if you actually bid on it. You then have to parse the first rows until you hit a youWON==1.

Comment: What exactly does '<>' do?

Comment: It means NOT EQUAL TO. (what in javascript or php is !=)

Comment: ah okay, well it does return an invalid amount of rows.. http://imageshack.com/a/img5/5289/2zye.png,, 0 rows are expected as I won all auctions. (WHERE winningTicketId IN (SELECT ticketId FROM AuctionBids)

Comment: Basicly your query obtains all tickets that were not the winning ticket, not the auctions that i lost.

Comment: Im gonna take another look. Maybe I misunderstood your question.

Comment: Updated question with test dump. Feel free to test on your localhost.

Comment: If the one from Mikhail did not work out, i'll come back at yours, but its logic seems valid so far. Could you make it work in sqlfiddle like Mikhail did? As i see your query contains some errors.

Comment: youWon seems always to be 1. YouBid does change though.

Comment: Yes, it doesn't work. I thought you were working with integers, but you have strings for ID's. So it cannot SUM.

Comment: seems to working better indeed, +1 for the effort. If this one works but the one from Mikhail doesnt, ill mark it as the answer

Comment: Well, unfortunately its not really THE answer since you still have to parse the result, so its not one query that answers the whole thing.

Comment: Seems to be working fine as it results in the expected values, however, the nYouBid is not the same as the winningTicketId, is there anyway to solve that?

Comment: I dont know why you would want that, but you can rewrite SUM( IF(AuctionBids.accountId=yourID,1,0) ) AS nYouBID as IF(SUM(IF(AuctionBids.accountId=yourID,1,0))>0,Auction.winningTicketId,0) AS nYouBID

Answer (score 0):

if you want it for your account id then, why u have used  ab.accountId NOT LIKE '". $_accountId ."' ?

```
 I think you should use ab.accountId LIKE '". $_accountId ."'
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, you can retrieve 'win', 'lose', 'participated' (not tested, but approach is right, I guess)

```
SELECT 'win', A.*, B,*
FROM Auction A INNER JOIN AuctionBids B
  ON A.id = B.auctionId
WHERE B.accountId = $me
  AND B.active = 0
  AND A.winningTicketId = B.bidID

UNION

SELECT 'lose', A.*, B,*
FROM Auction A INNER JOIN AuctionBids B
  ON A.id = B.auctionId
WHERE B.accountId = $me
  AND B.active = 0
  AND A.winningTicketId !=  B.bidID

UNION

SELECT 'ing', A.*, B,*
FROM Auction A INNER JOIN AuctionBids B
  ON A.id = B.auctionId
WHERE B.accountId = $me
  AND B.active = 1
```